# Symfony3.2 and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I have already posted this topic, but I have not yet resolved and I still come back.
I made a simple example on symfony and Ajax, to calculate the sum of two numbers, not error but when I click on button sum the answer does not display directly, but I must click Symfony Profiler and the answer is displayed .
Please help me

Controller:

```html
/**
     * @Route("/cal",name="cal_page")
     */
    public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
    {  
           $num1=$request->query->get('nbr1');
           $num2=$request->query->get('nbr2');      
            $som=$num1+$num2;
            return $this->render('ProjetBundle:Default:ajax.html.twig',array('som'=>$som));  
    }
```

View:

```html
Nombre1:
   <input type="text"  id="num1"><br><br>  
   Nombre2:
   <input type="text" id="num2"><br><br>  
   Resultat: 
   <input type="text"  id="resultat" value="{{som|default}}"><br>      
   <input type="button"  id="bttn" value="sum">
```

Here, when I click sum I should have had the answer on "resultat", but I have to go on profiler to have the answer

JS:

```js
{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#bttn" ).click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     var nbr1 = $('#num1').val();
     var nbr2 = $('#num2').val();
    if (isNaN(nbr1)|| isNaN(nbr2)) {
     alert('nbr1 ou nbr2 number');
    }
    else{
      $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       data:{nbr1:nbr1,nbr2:nbr2},
       url:'{{path('cal_page')}}',
       dataType:'html',
       success:function(data){                
        $("#resultat").html(data.som);   
       },
       error:function(){
        alert('attention');
       }
      });
            return false;
     }
    });  
});
</script>
{%endblock%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the success function.
You are saying to jquery you expect in data to find an html string. Then you look for som in data.

The code shoul be like this:

```
  success:function(data){                
            $("#resultat").html(data);      
          }
```

Comment: Thank you,Same case